# Facebook Graph API Post with a place

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to figure out what are the requirements for a javascript app to post to a users feed including a place.
So far I'm able to post a normal feed item (name, link, etc) but when I try to include a place I get this error:

```
{message: "An unknown error has occurred.", type: "OAuthException", code: 1}
```

Here's the json of what I'm trying to post:

```
var opts = {
   message : $scope.message,
   name : $scope.name,
   link : $scope.link,
   description : $scope.description,
   application:$scope.appID,
   place:{
      latitude:$scope.location.latitude,
      longitude:$scope.location.longitude,
      altitude:0,
      city:$scope.location.place
   }
};
```

latitude is 39

longitude is -9.12

city is 'Caldas da Rainha'

Is there a specific permission need to post referencing a place(only requiring publish_actions and user_tagged_places seems to be for reading)? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

Concerning the `place` field, the docs state that

> Page ID of a location associated with this post.

So, it's not possible to define a custom object and just add it to the JSON, you'll have to search for the `page_id` of the place you want to use in the post first.

You could either use the place name search (if you know where you are)

```
/search?q=Caldas+da+Rainha&type=place
```

or the proximity search if you have the coordinates

```
/search?q=&type=place&center=39,-9.12&distance=5000
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search